# how to change the back flutter app launcher icon color properly

Tags: flutter

I have added app launcher icon using this [link](https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-add-app-launcher-icons-in-flutter-bd92b0e0873a) and app launcher icon has changed but the problem is background has changed to orange color but the actual icon color is blue. Any idea on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

you should use **image** plugins as well to fix your issue, looks like

```
dev_dependencies: 
    flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.0"
    image: "^2.1.0"


flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon" 
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

And then you can run command :

```
flutter packages get
flutter packages pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: This hasn't fixed the issue for me (May 2022,  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2)

Answer (score 0):

For those still seeing this problem I discovered if you want to use the adaptive_icon_background you HAVE to also use the adaptive_icon_foreground.

```
flutter_icons:
 android: true
 ios: true
 remove_alpha_ios: true
 image_path: "assets/logo.png"
 adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/logo.png" 
 adaptive_icon_background: "assets/logobgcolor.png"
```